# How to insert value into html array with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and input type hidden:

```
<?php echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ref[]\" value=\"".$i."\" />"; ?>
```

Let's say `ref[]` has the values `{'1','2','3','4'}` and I want to use jQuery to insert 'a' in between '2' and '3'. Can I do it with jQuery?

How do I reference the html `ref[]` using jQuery? and insert value to the position I need?

Comment: You should share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Also show how look input on html code after parsing by php.

Comment: I have no idea because I am quite new to javascript/jq. I want to be able to do something like "array_splice" in php.

Comment: Basically I have a form and implementing function for user to insert rolls. So I have other input type="text" name="process[]" etc and when user click the add icon, it insert a new empty input roll so when this happen I want to insert the empty value in these array for data entry for form submit and later retrieve via $_POST

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to insert "a" between "2" and "3", then you can use `.replace()` string function.

```
$('input[name="ref[]"]').val($('input[name="ref[]"]').val().replace('"2","3"', '"2","a","3"'))
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PH4uF/3/

I'm not sure what is your requirement and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Muthu, that is quite close to what I want. Is there some kind of insert function instead of replace? My array size can be few hundreds element. The result is indeed what I was looking for is there something in JQ that does php array_splice?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your problem might be a bit off but if you are trying to find a certain input in an array of inputs using the name attribute you could use something like:

```
var myInput = $('#parentEle').find('input[name="' + ref[2] + '"]');
```

Basically use jQuery's find method to hunt down the input your looking for and change it.

Also, if you're just trying to change the name attribute use jQuery's attr() method like this:

```
myInput.attr('name', newValue);
```

Comment: Hi, is there a insert function so the current value is shifted down instead of replacing the value?

Comment: Are you trying to insert a whole new input element above another specific input element?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to insert a whole new input element above another specific input element. eg insert 'a' to '2','3' so 1,2,3,4 became 1,2,a,3,4.

Comment: And 1,2,3,4 are the names of the input tags?

Comment: If so, then try using jQuery's find method to hunt down the specific element and then use jQuery's before() method to insert the new element.  Like this: `$('#inputWrapper').find('input[name="2"]').before('<input name="a">');`

Comment: I use <input name="ref[]"/> then when submit in php I do $ref=$_POST('ref') then I do a for loop for($i=0; $i<count($ref); $i++) to get each element $ref[$i]

Comment: If the jQuery methods are a bit confusing, read through jQuery's API documentation.  [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com)